# Android Bitmap pixel color isn't correct

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, pixel

I've been trying to diagnose an issue with the output color of some Bitmap data in Android. It seems that, sometimes, the Bitmap color data generated does not have the same color that I provided to the eraseColor method.

I put together some sample code into an empty activity in Android Studio to demonstrate the issue:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Random random = new Random((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        int randomR = random.nextInt(256);
        int randomG = random.nextInt(256);
        int randomB = random.nextInt(256);
        int randomAlpha = random.nextInt(256);
        int androidColor = Color.argb(randomAlpha,randomR,randomG,randomB);
        int androidR = Color.red(androidColor);
        int androidG = Color.green(androidColor);
        int androidB = Color.blue(androidColor);
        int androidA = Color.alpha(androidColor);
        bitmap.eraseColor(androidColor);
        int pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(200, 200);
        int pixelR = Color.red(pixelColor);
        int pixelG = Color.green(pixelColor);
        int pixelB = Color.blue(pixelColor);
        int pixelA = Color.alpha(pixelColor);
        if(pixelR != randomR || pixelG != randomG || pixelB != randomB || pixelA != randomAlpha)
            System.out.println(String.format("[%d] Not matching - r(%d,%d,%d), g(%d,%d,%d), b(%d,%d,%d), a(%d,%d,%d)", i, randomR, androidR, pixelR, randomG, androidG, pixelG, randomB, androidB, pixelB, randomAlpha, androidA, pixelA));
        else
            System.out.println(String.format("[%d] MATCHING - r(%d,%d,%d), g(%d,%d,%d), b(%d,%d,%d), a(%d,%d,%d)", i, randomR, androidR, pixelR, randomG, androidG, pixelG, randomB, androidB, pixelB, randomAlpha, androidA, pixelA));
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

This is the output generated:

> [0] Not matching - r(234,234,234), g(153,153,149), b(148,148,149), a(24,24,24)
>   [1] Not matching - r(63,63,63), g(200,200,200), b(222,222,223), a(102,102,102)
>   [2] Not matching - r(15,15,14), g(82,82,83), b(210,210,211), a(92,92,92)
>   [3] MATCHING - r(21,21,21), g(231,231,231), b(155,155,155), a(227,227,227)
>   [4] Not matching - r(234,234,234), g(44,44,46), b(24,24,25), a(61,61,61)
>   [5] Not matching - r(165,165,167), g(50,50,52), b(156,156,156), a(49,49,49)
>   [6] Not matching - r(205,205,0), g(96,96,0), b(209,209,0), a(0,0,0)
>   [7] Not matching - r(39,39,38), g(238,238,239), b(132,132,130), a(47,47,47)
>   [8] MATCHING - r(25,25,25), g(103,103,103), b(16,16,16), a(227,227,227)
>   [9] Not matching - r(179,179,179), g(133,133,133), b(71,71,70), a(134,134,134)

Am I doing something clearly wrong? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks